# downloaded file cannot open(damage) codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a file with extension PDF and DOCX, and when i download it from my server, the file cannot opened and the size become 1kb, when in my server folder it has 199kb size. iam using database to store the file path and filename, here is my view to download the file

View

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/admin_controls/download_proposal/'.$hasil->ID_PEMESANAN.'')?>"><?php echo $details->FILE_NAME; ?></a>
```

and my controller

Admin_Controls.php

```
function download_proposal($id_pemesanan) {
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->model('gedung/gedung_model');
    $temp_id = substr($id_pemesanan, 7); //i cut the string because it content prefix string
    $data = $this->gedung_model->get_proposal_by_id($temp_id);
    $path = file_get_contents($data->PATH.$data->FILE_NAME);
    $file_name = $data->FILE_NAME;
    force_download($file_name, $data);
}
```

my model

Gedung_Model.php

```
public function get_proposal_by_id($id_pemesanan) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pemesanan_details WHERE ID_PEMESANAN = $id_pemesanan";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $hasil = $query->row();
    return $hasil;
}
```

my problem is just after i download the file, it becomes corrupted and cannot open, like i say the size become 1kb. all works well from user click to download until the download process

Thanks in advice

Comment: Are you sure that the script find the path of the files?What if you give "by hand" the path of the file?

Comment: the path i store in db sir, so the path and the file name i store in different column in db, here is the value of the path from the db = http://localhost/Warsito/assets/user-proposal/ 
and the value of file name in my db = antonprio_06122016_050646.pdf
as you can see i split them in my file_get_content, so after i split, the following string returned http://localhost/Warsito/assets/user-proposal/antonprio_06122016_050646.pdf

Comment: Are you sure that there is the "/" between $data->PATH and $data->FILE_NAME at $path = file_get_contents($data->PATH.$data->FILE_NAME); at your example at http://localhost/Warsito/assets/user-proposal/antonprio_06122016_050646.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would like to check the path .   You  can use absolute path of the file for testing purpose instead of dynamic generated path .